# OpenTK can't detect which OS I'm running on?

Tags: c#, mono, opentk

Consider the following piece of code.

```
using System;
using TK = OpenTK.Configuration;
// ...
    // Everything returns false on linux ??
    foreach (bool config in new bool[]{
            TK.RunningOnAndroid,
            TK.RunningOnLinux,
            TK.RunningOnMacOS,
            TK.RunningOnMono,
            TK.RunningOnSdl2,
            TK.RunningOnUnix,
            TK.RunningOnWindows,
            TK.RunningOnX11,
            }){
        Console.WriteLine(config.ToString());
    }
```

All entries print `false`. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

I'm running ubuntu 12.04, mono 2.10.8.1 and OpenTK 1.1.0.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good stackoverflow question. I would suggest filing a bug on https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues instead.

Comment: Regarding your issue, a fresh checkout from https://github.com/opentk/opentk appears to work correctly on Ubuntu 14.04. Try updating to OpenTK 1.1.1 or compiling from source directly. EDIT: make sure you have OpenTK.dll.config in your output directory - without this, OpenTK may fail to locate important OS libraries.